# flask admin redirect on wrong auth

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

So i am trying to redirect flask-admin admin page if the twitter oauth is not the correct one, but this will not redirect and i cannot figure out where i am wrong!

```
class AdminModelView(ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        if session['twitter_oauth']['user_id'] == 123456789:
            return True

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for('home'))



admin.add_view(AdminModelView(feed, db.session))
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(feeding, db.session))
admin = Admin(app, name='name', template_mode='bootstrap3')
```

I also tried adding the `AdminModelView` to `index_view` in Admin() but failing there as well...

Answer (score 0):

You may have already figured this out by now, but I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to register your model views before you create the Admin object.

In short, try:

```
admin = Admin(app, name='name', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(feed, db.session))
admin.add_view(AdminModelView(feeding, db.session))
```

If this isn't the issue, you'll probably need to provide additional information about what you've tried so far.

Comment: I figured it out, but without redirect, only a forbidden page. Had to wrap a `AdminIndexView` into a class and call the `is_accessible` there